# How can I select image in Semantic-UI-React Dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I made an language select Dropdown on my page by using semantic-ui-react dropdown like following.

[image]

And the js code is shown below.

```
import React from "react";
import {CustomDropListStyle} from './style.js'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const options = [
    {
        key: 'English',
        text: 'English',
        value: 'English',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'src/images/avatar/hawk.png' },
    },
    {
        key: 'Chinese',
        text: 'Chinese',
        value: 'Chinese',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'src/images/avatar/hawk.png' },
    },
    {
        key: 'Spanish',
        text: 'Spanish',
        value: 'Spanish',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'src/images/avatar/hawk.png' },
    },
    {
        key: 'French',
        text: 'French',
        value: 'French',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'src/images/avatar/gra.png' },
    },
    {
        key: 'German',
        text: 'German',
        value: 'German',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'src/images/avatar/hawk.png' },
    },
    {
        key: 'Portuguese',
        text: 'Portuguese',
        value: 'Portuguese',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'src/images/avatar/hawk.png' },
    },
]

class CustomDropList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <CustomDropListStyle>
                <Dropdown> 
                    fluid 
                    selection 
                    toggleItem 
                    options={options}
                </Dropdown>
            </CustomDropListStyle>
        );
    }
}
export default CustomDropList;
```

And then I tried to use Dropdown properties such as 'icon' and 'item' to show image in the header, but it didn't work.
Please help me to work out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with  tag like as following.
I think that if there is no way to insert object in same field, then try to insert it in other field and change its position.
The body of js code is:

```
import React from "react";
import {CustomDropListStyle} from './style.js';
import {Dropdown}  from 'semantic-ui-react';
import strings from "../../consts/string";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const options = [
    {
        key: 'English',
        text: 'English',
        value: 'en',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'img/images/avatar/en.png' },
    },
    {
        key: 'Chinese',
        text: 'Chinese',
        value: 'ch',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'img/images/avatar/ch.png' },
    },
    {
        key: 'Spanish',
        text: 'Spanish',
        value: 'sp',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'img/images/avatar/sp.png' },
    },
    {
        key: 'French',
        text: 'French',
        value: 'fr',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'img/images/avatar/fr.png' },
    },
    {
        key: 'German',
        text: 'German',
        value: 'ge',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'img/images/avatar/ge.png' },
    },
    {
        key: 'Portuguese',
        text: 'Portuguese',
        value: 'pt',
        image: { avatar: true, src: 'img/images/avatar/pt.png' },
    },
];
class CustomDropList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sel_lang:strings.getLanguage()
    };
  }

  exposedCampaignOnChange = (e, {value}) => {
    e.persist();
    this.setState({
      sel_lang: value,
    });
    console.log(this.state.sel_lang);
    strings.setLanguage(value);
    localStorage.setItem('lang', value);
  };

    render() {
      if( this.props.isLogged ){
        let label_lang = 'English';
        switch (this.state.sel_lang) {
          case 'en':
            label_lang = 'English';
            break;
          case 'ch':
            label_lang = '汉语';
            break;
          case 'sp':
            label_lang = 'English';
            break;
          case 'fr':
            label_lang = 'English';
            break;
          case 'pt':
            label_lang = 'English';
            break;
          case 'ge':
            label_lang = 'English';
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        return (
          <CustomDropListStyle>
            <h1 className="sellang_lbl_logged">{label_lang}</h1>
            <img className="sellang_img_logged" src={`img/images/avatar/${this.state.sel_lang}.png`}/>
          </CustomDropListStyle>
        );
      }else {
        return (
          <CustomDropListStyle>
            <img className="sellang_img" src={`img/images/avatar/${this.state.sel_lang}.png`}/>
            <Dropdown
              fluid
              options={options}
              onChange={this.exposedCampaignOnChange}
              defaultValue={strings.getLanguage()}
            />
          </CustomDropListStyle>
        );
      }
    }
}

CustomDropList.propTypes = {
  isLogged: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default CustomDropList;
```

And css code is:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const CustomDropListStyle = styled.label`
    .ui.fluid.dropdown, .ui.fluid.dropdown:hover .ui.upward.dropdown>.menu {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 170px;
        max-width: 170px;
        font-size:16px;
        border:0;
    }

    .ui.selection.active.dropdown:hover {
        box-shadow:none;
        font-size:16px;
        border-radius:0;

    }
    .ui.active.visible.fluid.selection.dropdown {
        font-size:14px;
        border-radius:0;
    }
    .ui.dropdown .menu {
        left: 0;        
        position:relative;      
    }
    .ui.dropdown{
         margin-top:6%;
         margin-right:1%;
         text-align:center;
    }
    .ui.selection.dropdown {
        border-bottom:1px solid #97a5ad;
        border-radius:0;
    }
    .ui.selection.active.dropdown {
        border-bottom:0px solid #97a5ad;
    }
    .ui.avatar.image {
        border-radius:50%;
    }
    .visible.transition{
        border:1px solid #97a5ad !important;    
    }
    .ui.selection.dropdown .menu, .ui.selection.dropdown .menu:hover {

        border-radius: 6px;
        margin:4px 0 4px 0;
        border:1px solid #97a5ad !important;
    }
    .ui.upward.selection.dropdown.visible {
        border-radius:0 !important;
    }
    .ui.upward.dropdown>.menu, .ui.upward.dropdown>.menu:hover {
        border-radius: 6px;
        margin:16px 0 4px 0;
        border:1px solid #97a5ad !important;
    }

    i.af.flag::before{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        border-radius:50%;
    }
    i.icon.dropdown::before, .ui.dropdown>.dropdown.icon:before {
         border-width: 5px 5px 0;
         content: ' ';
         display: block;
         margin-top: -ceil(2.5);
         position: absolute;
         right: 1%;
         width: 9px;
         height: 9px;
         border: solid #97a5ad;
         border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
         -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
         -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
         transform: rotate(45deg);
         vertical-align:middle !important;         
    }
    .ui.dropdown>.dropdown.icon {
        margin: 2px 0 0 1em;
    }        
    .ui.dropdown .menu>.item, .active selected item {
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        border: none;
        height: auto;
        text-align: left;
        border-top: none;
        line-height: 1em;
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
        padding: .78571429rem 1.14285714rem!important;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-transform: none;
        font-weight: 400;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    }
    .sellang_img {
        width:20%;
        height:20%;
        float:left;
    }
    .sellang_img_logged {
        float:right;
         width:40%;
        height:40%;
    }
    .sellang_lbl_logged {
      vertical-align:middle;
      margin:-25% 12%;
    }    
`;
```

And then the result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1f0Q.png)

Comment: Only this way? If any other please provide me